# Is it possible to use RGB image with decimal values when feeding training data to CNN?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, tensorflow, python, regression

I am working with four grayscale images of float32 data type to perform regression using Keras. Three images are stacked using `np.dstack` to form a RGB data-set. The last grayscale image is used as label. The grayscale images contains different variations, including [0 , 790.65], [ 150.87 , 260.45], [ -2.74174 , 2.4126 ], [-32.927 , 69.333].

If I convert the images to unit8, the maximum values for the first and second image will be 255 and the decimal values for all images will be lost.  I am having difficulty and struggling to find the solution for using the image in the original data type (float32) when I try to use `ImageDataGenerator` and `flow_from_directory`. Can anyone suggest way for that?

Comment: Data size is too low. And the loss of information of casting from float to int won't be that high.

Comment: Your images should be normalized. You can choose any range (e.g. [-1, 0] or [0, 1]), but the main condition is that it must represent the intensities of the pixels and has to  be able to be scaled back to the original range [0, 255]. btw `matplolib` can plot normalized images in range [0, 1]